Почему не работает HTML теги в сообщение телеграм на Java (telegrambots)?
Я хочу что бы отправленное сообщение, которое отправляет бот было жырными я использую html тег <b>. Телеграм отправляет Привет! Почему он не отправялет жырным шрифтом?
if (messageText.equals("/start")) {
            currentDialog = DialogMode.GPT;
            String mainText = "<b>Привет!</b>";
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            sendMessage.enableHtml(true);
            sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(message.getChatId()));
            sendMessage.setParseMode("HTML");
            sendMessage.setText(mainText);

            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DeleteMessage deleteMessage = new DeleteMessage();
            deleteMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
            deleteMessage.setMessageId(message.getMessageId());

            try {
                execute(deleteMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }


Вы включаете HTML, но не удаляете предыдущее сообщение до того, как отправляете новое. Проблема может возникать из-за порядка выполнения операций.
Попробуйте изменить порядок удаления сообщения и отправки нового.

@VladimirGlinskikh спасибо помогли
